# Update TWiki or Migrate to Foswiki?

Tags: wiki

In my company, we have a big old TWiki portal. The installed version is 4.1.1 from 2007. And we want to update it now, but our problem is:

**Should we update to the a newer TWiki version or, instead, migrate to Foswiki?**

Our concerns are:

- Today, they are equivalent in features?
- Which one will do better in the future?

Comment: I'm similarly looking at upgrading TWiki or migrating away.  Was looking at MoinMoin as one possibility.

Answer (score 1):

1 - It's quite difficult to feel the difference in features for basic
installations of both TWiki and Foswiki. I'd say that they are the
same.

Also Foswiki already have included compatibility level for stuff
migrating from TWiki such as plugins, etc.

2 - As per news from official Foswiki blog, the most active
contributors have joined Foswiki already. All my recent wiki
installations based on Foswiki and I'm quite happy with them. Let it
be the way I support Foswiki community.

Read the Foswiki documentation - it should help you to make the right
decision.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I've upgraded 7 TWiki installations to Foswiki.

As of now (November 2009) it looks as if about 200 bugs are present in TWiki
which have been fixed in Foswiki.  Not surprising as Foswiki now has about 15
active developers -- to 1.5 for TWiki after the great corporate lockout.

So the featureset is currently with Foswiki -- and the future is clearly with them.

Besides, the switchover is no more difficult than doing a version-to-version 
upgrade (they are the same codebase).  And the new Foswiki way of doing future
upgrades is a snap.  Unpack a special tarball and you're done.  After previous
painful TWiki upgrades, it's a snap (they copied this technique, by the way,
recently-- but who knows how long they'll be around to keep it up -- or if
they'll ever find the manpower or community to make the backlog of bugs go down).

Big companies are switching or have switched.  Yahoo, which has the world's largest TWiki installation, has a hiring opportunity open for a Foswiki developer to spearhead their migration and continued customization.  Why Foswiki?  Because that's where the features and bugfixes are coming from -- it's the only active community driving innovation.